# SweetAlert2 with timer not working as expected

Tags: sweetalert2

I need to set a boolean property to true or false based on whether the alert window was closed by the confirm button or the timer. Issue is, the .then() code block is skipped and never run.

Here is what I tried

```
shouldPost: boolean = false;
Swal.fire({
            timer: 5000,
            text: 'Sending reading ....',
            confirmButtonColor: '#C64EB2',
            confirmButtonText: 'Cancel Send'
          }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isDismissed) {
              this.shouldPost = true;
            }
          })
```